# wkhtmltopdf and JQuery flot render PDF error

Tags: flot, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using JQuery Flot for render one or more chart. So, when i try to use wkhtmltopdf for render chart to PDF, it only render the graph's axis and graph's background is black color.

My Enviroment:
 + Windows Server 2003 standard edition SP2
 + Apache 2.2.22
 + PHP 5.3.2
 + JQuery 1.8.2
 + Flot 0.8.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [wkhtmltopdf only renders axes of flot chart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883153/wkhtmltopdf-only-renders-axes-of-flot-chart)